# Strange xcolor error behaviour

Tags: errors, color

Using \section{\color{red}{text}} sometimes produces an error, and sometimes not, depending on the amount of preceding text. This behaviour is extremely cumbersome, you can add or remove harmless text to switch behaviour without finding the real source of error.

Here is a minimal example (documentclass book is important):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum %

aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa a

\section{\color{red}{Color}} \end{document}
```

I use lualatex (but also pdflatex of latex reproduces the same behaviour)
This minimal example produces the following error message:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `RED'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.31 \end{document}
```

If you remove one block of the aaa's, or add one \lipsum more, than the error does not appear!!

I'm *not* looking for a solution, to work around the problem, see 
[Error with xcolor package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64298/error-with-xcolor-package).
And I actually do not care to much about, if \section{\color{red}{text}} produces an error or not, but it should do it always or never, and should not depend on the inoccent context, which actually has nothing to do with the error. I have a lot of \color commands im my text, and it was extremely cumbersome to find the real source (and moreover to find this relatively easy "minimal" example), since I had the line \section{\color{red}{text}} in my text for a long time already without any problems, and suddenly it causes an error, because some innocent text was added somewhere else. This is no fun!! ;-) I hope this can be chanced.

Thanks, Georg

Comment: You shouldn't use color arguments within `section` and friends. The automatic header uppercases everything, and `RED` is undefined. We have a duplicate question already.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Then it should produce an error if I do so, then I know, but sometimes it does not.

Comment: The problem is the header. Use `\section[Text for the header]{Text with \color{red} blbl}`. And you should care about errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks anyway, although I wrote that I'm not looking for a solution. My original post is mainly addressed to people who are interested in improving user experience and quality of texlive. Like I explained in my post, it was quite cumbersome to find the error and it would have saved me a lot of time if \section{\color{red}{text}} always produces an error, or never.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: OK, now I understand the problem and why it cannot be fixed like I wish it could be. It just depends if a header is produced or not, and this depends on the surrounding context. Wow, this is sofisticated.

Comment: TeX gives an error when the text with the `\color` command is needed to typeset the running header. Depending on the context the section title appears in the running header (e.g. if the section is long enough, or the preceding text is long enough such the section is still active when a right-hand page closes), or not (short section, or new section without problematic title starts in time). TeX can complain about errors only when it has encountered the erroneous code.

Comment: @GeorgGrafendorfer: The quality of TeXLive? This has nothing to do with the quality of TeXLive, MikTeX etc. but just with the correct and wrong usage of TeX/LaTeX and its packages. Reading the manual helps in most cases ;-)

Comment: @GeorgGrafendorfer It is difficult to see how you could detect the error earlier, it is bad style to use colour commands (or any formatting)  in a section heading but only an error if those commands are used together with other formatting commands. But if you do not want an answer that says how to avoid the error here, it seems that this isn't really a question that can be answered on this site.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Which manual do you exactly mean, that addresses this specific issue? ;-)