# How to change the color of a section in ACM template?

Tags: sectioning, color, acmart

I am trying to change the color of the name of a section in ACM template.

`\section{\color{red} My Section}`

I have found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64298/error-with-xcolor-package) but it did not work.

It gives the error of `Undefined color RED`

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[acmlarge]{acmart} 

\settopmatter{printacmref=false}% 
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}% 
\renewcommand\footnotetextauthorsaddresses[1]{}% \pagestyle{plain} 
\fancyfoot{} 

\makeatletter 
\def\runningfoot{\def\@runningfoot{}} 
\def\firstfoot{\def\@firstfoot{}} 
\def\@copyrightspace{\relax} 
\makeatother 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables


\begin{document} 

\title{My Title} 

\author{Me} 

\maketitle 

\thispagestyle{empty} 

\section{\color{red} My Section}

This is my file. This is an algorithm, called \textsc{exp3}. Numbers like $1,2,3$ are not small caps. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the `log` file, the error says `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color RED.` while you are using the `red` one! 
It's because of changing the case by `section` macro, therefore you have to prevent this action. 
The following will fix your issue by preventing uppercase. `\lowercase` macro also forces latex not to convert to uppercase.

```
\protected\def\mycolor{\color{red}}

\section{\mycolor My Section}
\section{\lowercase{\color{green}}My Section}
```

[image]