# Package tikz interfering with package xcolor

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have following preamble,

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[
        twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,
        footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
        dottedtoc, % Make page numbers in the table of contents flushed right with dots leading to them
        BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
        ngerman,american, % Languages, change this to your language(s)
        ]{scrreprt} 
        
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

This compiling fine and producing PDF, but i want to add a tikz figure so upon adding the package `\usepackage{tikz}`, the compiler is throwing following error,

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined
> color `Maroon'.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have uploaded whole project [here](https://www.overleaf.com/4873237927fsbrsjsdqppz) for easy edit and reference. Thanks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64298/error-with-xcolor-package

Comment: I have already tried that and plenty of other links. No use.

Comment: do you get an option class error before?

Comment: I am new to this, so less idea about class error. Here is the project thom https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f525f113cc7150001ba9770

Comment: I will not go to a project and debug it. Search the log-file for errors and try to make a small and complete example demonstrating the problem that you can post here.

Comment: The log file is stating the same thing 43 times. Which i have already included in question.

Comment: If you tried to add the `dvipsnames` or `svgnames` option (or both) to the document class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Maroon` color is one of `svgnames` colors. You need to load this list when `xcolor` package is loaded.

The easiest solution would be to add option `svgnames` to `scrreprt` options list. This way it will be applied when `TiKz` loads `xcolor` package.

Comment: Thank you very much. Addding `svgnames` worked. I also took the liberty to read your interviews meanwhile. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mercurial interviews????

Comment: I'm sorry, i was reading Ulrike Fischer's interviews. The person making comments in question above. My bad.